# How to specify destination path using mget command

Tags: ftp

I am trying to copy multiple files from Linux machine to Windows using `mget`. Files are getting downloaded, but I'm not able to specify the destination directory (Windows directory)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [`mget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-mget) does not allow you to explicitly specify target local directory.

It always downloads the files to the current local working directory.

Though, you can change the local working directory using [`lcd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-lcd) command:

```
ftp> lcd C:\path
Local directory now C:\path.
ftp> mget *.*
```